# My application is not opening

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I used Parse query in order to retrieve data in my recycler view. Whenever I launch my app it crashes. My codes are:

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

   mAdapter=new CardAdapter(new ArrayList<>(), new CardAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
           switch(position){
               case 0: //Opening an Activity 

           }

       }
   });

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

NatureItem.java

```
@ParseClassName("Nature")
public class NatureItem extends ParseObject {
private String mName;
private String mDes;
private int mThumbnail;


public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.mName = name;
}

public String getDes() {
    return mDes;
}

public void setDes(String des) {
    this.mDes = des;
}

public int getThumbnail() {
    return mThumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
    this.mThumbnail = thumbnail;
 }
}
```

CardAdapter.java

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {


List<NatureItem> mItems;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}


public CardAdapter(ArrayList<Object> itemsData, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    super();

    mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    //this.mData = itemsData;

   mItems = new ArrayList<NatureItem>();
   NatureItem nature = new NatureItem();
    ParseQuery<NatureItem> query = new ParseQuery<NatureItem>("Nature");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<NatureItem>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<NatureItem> list, ParseException e) {
            if(e!= null){
                //      Toast.makeText(CardAdapter.this, "Error " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            for (NatureItem nature: list){
                NatureItem newNatureItem=new NatureItem();
                newNatureItem.setName(nature.getName());
                newNatureItem.setDes(nature.getDes());
                newNatureItem.setThumbnail(nature.getThumbnail());
                mItems.add(newNatureItem);
            }

        }
    });


}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    NatureItem nature = mItems.get(i);
    viewHolder.tvNature.setText(nature.getName());
    viewHolder.tvDesNature.setText(nature.getDes());
    viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());
    viewHolder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, i);
        }

    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imgThumbnail;
    public TextView tvNature;
    public TextView tvDesNature;
    public View container;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        container = itemView;
        imgThumbnail = (ImageView)
itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
        tvNature = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);
        tvDesNature = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_des_nature);

    }
 }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aj.card_view" >

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.aj.parse_implementation.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.aj.parse_implementation.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".NoteAppApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

XML files

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

recycler_view_card_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="338dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="#FFCA28"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_nature"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#5c1b1b1b"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_thumbnail"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_des_nature"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:textColor="#ff272727"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_nature"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Log Report is presented below:

```
11-03 17:19:46.982    2227-2227/com.aj.card_view I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-03 17:19:47.033    2227-2227/com.aj.card_view W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.aj.card_view-2/lib/arm
11-03 17:19:47.140    2227-2255/com.aj.card_view D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-03 17:19:47.151    2227-2227/com.aj.card_view D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-03 17:19:47.151    2227-2227/com.aj.card_view E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aj.card_view, PID: 2227
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
            at com.aj.card_view.CardAdapter$1.done(CardAdapter.java:46)
            at com.aj.card_view.CardAdapter$1.done(CardAdapter.java:40)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

NoteAppApplication.java

```
package com.aj.card_view;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

 /**
 * Created by Anubhav on 11/3/2015.
 */
public class NoteAppApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(NatureItem.class);
    Parse.initialize(this, "key",       
"key2");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
 }
}
```

Comment: hey, where have you initialized parse? Before using any parse operation, you have to initialize it properly, ` Parse.initialize(this, "app-id", "client-key");` , I dont see this in your code :/

Comment: I have added that.I thought it was obvious so I didn't add it in my codes. But I will edit it